# I am unable to print properly in draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I just started using draw.io and every time I try to print, either directly from the drawing or exported from the file, either I get a tiny nothing or it's so big it doesn't come close to fitting on the paper.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest exporting to PDF (File->Export and select PDF) and then printing the resulting PDF.

Comment: works for any printing problem!

Answer (score 1):

After much trial and error, seems to be a problem with one or more of your objects going over an invisible margin that surrounds the page.

Try to reduce the size of your group of objects, or have the objects continue on a second page, leaving enough room for the margin.

Answer (score 0):

I notice thread is old, but this may help.

I was experiencing the same print issues. nothing would calibrate by default.
I found I had to create a template file with 8.5x11 and 11x17 portrait and landscape pages (TABs). Then tested and strictly use for holding the calibrations.
When creating a new draw io I just duplicate the template file, rename it, then choose the paper size and orientation needed. create a duplicate of that tab and rename that too.

- Best font to print with so far is courier at 10pt.
- The biggest object is 1" and smallest .125". (Switch units to inches)
- Grid size I bounce between .125" and .0625" for shape adjustments. Note units will round themselves up on the UI. so .125" may appear .130.

Hope you find this helpful.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/152257)